# Joomla Not able to add new Currency while adding product

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla VirtueMart 3.0.10, to add new product.
For Product currency its showing Euro as Default.

When i am trying to configure same, for select Currency and List of acceptable currency, dropbox is empty.. and its not allowing to select current.

I need to modify Default currecy be US $

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Joomla related questions go here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Virtuemart -> Shop -> Edit Shop

In right page you can add all currency you want.

If not appear in the list go to

> Settings -> Currency

And activate your currency